# The number of challot for Yom Tov?

Tags: challah-shabbat-bread

How many challot should be on the table for Yom tov,for example Rosh Hashana? Two, or, one can be just fine?

Comment: Related  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13933/759

Answer (score 6):

The Shulchan Aruch (OC:529) paskens וחייב לבצע על שתי ככרות - Two loaves.  The Mishna Brurah explains (ס"ק י) that the Mann also didn't fall on Yom Tov, so there was a double portion the day before.  See both the [Shulchan Aruch and Mishna Brurah inside on Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.529.1?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.529.10&lang2=en).

[*(source)*](http://www.aish.com/atr/Lechem-Mishna-Double-Loaves.html)

Comment: IIRC, Rash"I or Seforno discusses the phrasing in the verse in Shemot that discusses the double portion that it is ref. to *Eruv Tavshilin*, and a double portion may have fallen when Yom Tov was on the 6th day of the week.

Comment: Rambam Shabbat (30:9) similarly requires _lechem mishneh_ on _yom tov_.